# How to properly include an http C library into an Android Project?

Tags: c, java-native-interface, http-post

I am making an Android Project and I am trying to make a post request using HTTPS to a server. To make the post request I am requires to use JNI so I need to implement this in `C`.
My idea was to use a library that I could include into my project as i have done with the [minizip library here](https://github.com/nmoinvaz/minizip).

I found this library [here](https://github.com/HISONA/https_client) that seemed to me light engough and could server my purpose. I included in the folder `c` as you can also see below the files `ca_cert.h`, `https.c` and `https.h` along with the folder `mbedtls` exactly as is found on the github project.

```
├── app.iml
├── build.gradle
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── src
    ├── androidTest
    │   └── java
    │       └── etc
    ├── main
    │   ├── AndroidManifest.xml
    │   ├── c
    │   │   ├── ca_cert.h
    │   │   ├── https.c
    │   │   ├── https.h
    │   │   ├── mbedtls
    │   │   │   ├── etc
    │   │   ├── native-lib.c
    │   │   ├── pathfinder.c
    │   │   ├── pathfinder.h
    │   │   ├── post_data.c
    │   │   ├── post_data.h
    │   │   ├── third
    │   ├── java
    │   │   └── etc
    │   └── res
    │       ├── etc
    └── test
        └── java
            └── etc
```

As you can see in the tree structure above I have a `CMakeLists.txt` in the root directory and in `src/main/c/` you will see the files and the folder i took from the the https library mentioned.

The contents of the `CMakeLists.txt` are the following

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_library(    # Sets the name of the library.
                native-lib

                # Sets the library as a shared library.
                SHARED

                # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
                src/main/c/native-lib.c
                src/main/c/ca_cert.h
                src/main/c/https.h
                )

include_directories(native-lib SHARED src/main/c/mbedtls/include)

#add_definitions(-DHAVE_ZLIB)
find_library( PRE_BUILD_ANDROID_LIB android)
find_library( log-lib log)
find_library(z-lib z)


target_link_libraries( native-lib

                       ${PRE_BUILD_ANDROID_LIB}
                       ${log-lib}
                       ${z-lib}
                       )
```

I am missing something though for sure cause when i attempt to run a simple example like the following

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_example_example_do_post(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject  this ) {

        NSV_LOGE("post_data starts\n");
            char *url;
            char data[1024], response[4096];
            int  i, ret, size;

            HTTP_INFO hi1, hi2;


            // Init http session. verify: check the server CA cert.
            http_init(&hi1, FALSE);
            http_init(&hi2, TRUE);

        url = "http://httpbin.org/get?message=https_client";

        ret = http_get(&hi1, url, response, sizeof(response));

        return 0;
}
```

I get

```
../../../../src/main/c/native-lib.c:56: error: undefined reference to 'http_init'
../../../../src/main/c/native-lib.c:57: error: undefined reference to 'http_init'
../../../../src/main/c/native-lib.c:61: error: undefined reference to 'http_get'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
            src/main/c/ca_cert.h
            src/main/c/https.h
```

with

```
            src/main/c/https.c
```

in `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: thank you for your answer
result now is
`src/main/c/https.c:465:58: error: use of undeclared identifier 'IPPROTO_UDP'`

Comment: @kampias That's a different matter. That's a compiler error. Obviously the library you're using isn't flawless. Try inluding `<netinet/ip.h>` in `https.h`.

Comment: yes i thought so, i have added the suggestion but now a lot of `undefined reference` error appeared - [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/dwJQqqvc)

Comment: @kampias The https-client you copied the three files from depends on [mbedtls](https://github.com/HISONA/https_client/tree/master/mbedtls). But I can't help you with that.

Comment: Yes indeed it does , that is why I have included the folder in the `c` directory. And if you check in the `CMakeLists.txt` I use `include_directories` for it. Should I put something additional in the  `CMakeLists.txt`??

Comment: @kampias It's not sufficient to only add something to the search path for include files. The whole library needs to be compiled.